# How to get the ListView with carousel scrolling on Android?

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I would like to have a `ListView` that scrolls in a carousel way, so when you scroll to the bottom and continue scolling, it should get back to the top element.

I do not want to use `ViewSwitcher`, nor `ViewFlipper`.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You might want to see this http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/b3c89d38d71f69d5/589906ce9de41a5a?lnk=gst&q=circular+listViews#589906ce9de41a5a

Comment: That is what I was afraid of ;-). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try implementing a carousel view. You could refer to these :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503892/android-carousel-view

[Android image carousel view (sense like)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502282/android-image-carousel-view-sense-like)

[Carousel view in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756321/carousel-view-in-android)