# Carousel view in Android

Tags: android

I need to implement **Carousel view in Android**.

I searched in the net but didn't find any sample code for implementing.

Kindly send me any sample code / Url which will be helpful in developing the same.

Comment: Hi try this .... http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/androcarousel.aspx  if you complete it let me know what happen...

Comment: @chiranjib do u know how to make this http://code.google.com/p/android-ui-utils/downloads/detail?name=CarouselExample.zip&can=1&q= look like this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/androcarousel.aspx ??

Comment: @Ganapathy Very nice example. Can i have same but in vertical orientation. I have a requirement of a vertical carousel.

Comment: @SureshSharma try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206586/how-to-create-vertical-carousel-in-android

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might peruse the [CarouselView](http://code.google.com/p/android-ui-utils/downloads/detail?name=CarouselExample.zip&can=1&q=) example code mentioned in the "[Designing Android UIs for Phones and Tablets](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WGIU2JX1U5Y)" session at Google I/O 2011.

The example makes heavy use of the [Renderscript](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/renderscript.html) framework, released with Android 3.0.  Variations of the CarouselView component were used in several of the applications within Honeycomb including Books and YouTube when creating 3D carousel effects.

Comment: sadly, the GUI part of renderscript got deprecated. is there maybe another way to achieve it, maybe a way that works on older versions too?

Comment: Very nice example. Can i have same but in vertical orientation. I have a requirement of a vertical carousel.

Comment: Can you help me on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33219942/horitzontalscrollview-or-carrousel)? :D