# How to create Vertical Carousel in android?

Tags: android, listview, carousel, coverflow

I want to implement vertical carousel in android.I have searched lot of things about it,Finally i found that horizontal carousel example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel). Can any body know that how to convert this horizontal carousel into vertical carousel.

And also i have tried this .[Link](http://developer.sonyericsson.com/wp/2010/06/23/android-tutorial-making-your-own-3d-list-part-3/) .This 3d listview gives rotation of the each element but i want to implement whole list should be in 3d. Can any body give suggestions please...

Comment: Nice question hmm..i think you have already solved it?

Comment: Yes i got the solution for it...

Comment: :then Romain Piel deserve for bounty

Comment: LINK to get view as vertical is not working can you please post the code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want a vertical pager, try [that library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager) written by Jake Warthon. It's perfectly coded and completely up to date with Android SDK.

The best way to work with 3d is to work with renderscript. I won't be really helpful on that topic.

Answer (score 2):

This following code is used to display the carousel in vertical view. I just modified code in this url. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel .This is works fine for nexus-landscpape. And also i used this [LINK](http://tutorials.flashmymind.com/2009/03/vertical-3d-carousel-with-actionscript-3/) to get view as vertical.

```
private void Calculate3DPosition(CarouselItem child, int diameter,
            float angleOffset) {
        angleOffset = angleOffset * (float) (Math.PI / 180.0f);
        float y = (float) (diameter / 2 * Math.sin(angleOffset)) + diameter / 2
                - child.getWidth() / 2;
        float z = diameter / 2 * (1.0f - (float) Math.cos(angleOffset));
        float x = (float) (-   diameter / 2 * Math.cos(angleOffset) * 0.5);
        child.setX(x + 250);
        child.setZ(z);
        child.setY(y - 150);
    }
```

Comment: LINK to get view as vertical is not working can you please post the code.

Comment: can you please tell how you set view as vertical.

Comment: Hello, Ramesh i am using same link which you have listed in your question. i want to create vertical carousel animation in portrait but it will not good. so can you send me code please ?

Comment: this is the which i get this animation but it is horizontal http://horribile.blogspot.in/2011/11/android-3d-carousel.html  i want this in vertical way, i tried to modify Calculate3DPosition method but it is not work correctly, need your help.