# How to create list with carousel effect in android

Tags: java, android, carousel, coverflow, custom-lists

I've gone through with many solutions but still looking for best. I want to do something like [image: this]

This should be a list containing custom cells and it shall be showing one view highlighted at one time and two adjacent views(pre/post) must be shown slightly.

If anybody have any experience in this work please share. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not kinda mobile/design developer, but certainly you need [thread](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html) here

Comment: Hello. Can you please share how you solve it ? I need same 3d carousel horizontally.

Comment: Have you implement it ?

Answer (score 0):

[for detail visit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206586/how-to-create-vertical-carousel-in-android/9291321#9291321)

```
private void Calculate3DPosition(CarouselItem child, int diameter,
            float angleOffset) {
        angleOffset = angleOffset * (float) (Math.PI / 180.0f);
        float y = (float) (diameter / 2 * Math.sin(angleOffset)) + diameter / 2
                - child.getWidth() / 2;
        float z = diameter / 2 * (1.0f - (float) Math.cos(angleOffset));
        float x = (float) (-   diameter / 2 * Math.cos(angleOffset) * 0.5);
        child.setX(x + 250);
        child.setZ(z);
        child.setY(y - 150);
    }
```