# Android image carousel view (sense like)

Tags: android, image, view, carousel

I have a Android phone with HTC sense and there is a standard musicplayer installed on my device.

This musicplayer has a nice way to scroll through the albums, I think the iPod has the same way of showing this.

I searched the internet for it but I couldnt find it...

Is there a standard control to do this or, if not, what is the best solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi you have to implement this kind of control, piece of cake thanks to Neil Davies.

[Cover Flow Widget](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/01/android-coverflow-widget.html)

and this is the new version

[Android Coverflow Widget V2](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html)